# Dependence on DependencyObject and DependencyProperty

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I'm building a Silverlight application and one of my caveats from last time was that if you need anything done right in Silverlight/WPF way you'd need to model your objects as a DependecyObject and use DependencyProperty(ies)

I find this model to be rather cumbersome, requiring static fields and initializers in half the classes I use, so is it a good idea to use the good-old event-driven (observer pattern?) in place of DependencyObject?

I'm aiming to minimize code bloat and boiler plates (I hate them) and really would like to know if anyone with experience in Silverlight/WPF has any tips/techniques for keeping usage of DependencyObject and DependencyProperty to a minimum?

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, in Silverlight you cannot inherit DependencyObjects, and so you should (and have to) implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead.

Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged has many advantages over DependencyObjects (I will abbreviate this DO to make it easier) and using DependencyProperties (DPs):

- This is more lightweight
- Allows you more freedom in modeling your objects
- Can be serialized easily
- You can raise the event when you want, which can be useful in certain scenarios, for example when you want to bundle multiple changes in only one UI operation, or when you need to raise the event even if the data didn't change (to force redraw...)

On the other hand, inheriting DOs in WPF have the following advantages:

- Easier to implement especially for beginners.
- You get a callback mechanism (almost) for free, allowing you to be notified when the property value changes
- You get a coercion mechanism with allows you to define rules for max, min and present value of the property.

There are other considerations, but these are the main.

I think the general consensus is that DPs are great for controls (and you can implement a CustomControl with custom DPs even in Silverlight), but for data objects you should rather implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

HTH,
Laurent

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on which objects you are referring to. If the object is intended to sit in the XAML tree, its best to use DependencyProperties (and thus inherit DependencyObject - which all UIElements do) to allow all the benefits that DependencyProperties provide (being animatable, binding, optional automatic child inheritance, etc). I highly recommend you read the [MSDN overview on DependencyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) if you haven't already.

If the object is an data entity (ie. you are binding its values TO something in the XAML tree) then there is no need to inherit from DependencyObject. If the properties on the object are read-write you may want to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx), which will allow bindings to automatically update when the value changes.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Richard that it depends on the purpose of your class, but as a note it seems that you CAN inherit from DependencyObject directly in Silverlight 2.0 Release, without having to inherit from UIElement or UserControl.  At least, I'm doing that in my (SilverLight 2.0 RTW) app.

[System.Windows.DependencyObject on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject(VS.95).aspx)

> It is ***not typical*** to derive directly from DependencyObject for most scenarios. Instead you might derive from a specific control, from one of the control base classes (ContentControl; Control; ItemsControl), from FrameworkElement, or from non-control classes that still participate in UI such as Panel or Grid. Deriving from DependencyObject might be appropriate if you are defining a business or data storage object where you want dependency properties to be active, or if you are creating a service support class that will own attached properties.

HTH